# Azure Function - Error building configuration in an external startup class

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I'm using an Azure Function in ".Net 8", I'm trying to use a custom start-up by following this article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

here is the custom start-up:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Xml.Linq;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace Function;

public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    }

    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var context = builder.GetContext();

        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "function.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"function.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
}
```

But When I run the function, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation '2fff8edb-0e76-4789-b51b-bdcbea0ad107'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
Press any key to continue....[2023-12-20T21:35:26.832Z] Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation 'e8145c61-4903-402b-b164-3f9c3866817e'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation '7b68f1b4-7d74-4221-afe2-13ec1ab77ef7'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation '9c04f584-294b-4f01-9c70-ba1df345ce13'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation '2f294885-00a4-46a1-b4f8-5cb7c55ac9b0'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation '0b2168d4-efdc-4cdc-8100-2575c5b0a77a'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error building configuration in an external startup class.
Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation 'd2ba0a10-bbe7-4dea-a11d-ca64de26ea84'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Function: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here are also my package references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.Functions.Worker" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Abstractions" Version="1.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.7.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}
```

I looked at similar questions and problems in different links but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Downgrade the version of package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` to 7.0.0 and check.

Comment: I did it but the strange part is the same errors as before 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0'! (Rebuilt for sure)

Comment: Which trigger are you using?

Comment: I'm using QueueTrigger like here: `[QueueTrigger("myqueue-items")]`

Comment: I think your function is .NET 8 Isolated function. As per the [document you have provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), the startup class you have used doesn't support Isolated functions. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/o5ZQSbW.png). Check if this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#start-up-and-configuration) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***As I mentioned in the comments, .NET 8 Isolated function doesn't have a separate Startup class.***

The **Startup class** you are using supports **In-Process Functions**.

[image]

[MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#start-up-and-configuration) states that isolated functions contain a `Program.cs` file which provides *complete access to the Host instance* for setting any code configurations & dependencies.

***Refer [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples/FunctionApp) for sample project of .NET 8 Isolated function.***

- Created a .NET 8 Isolated function:

**My Program.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        configBuilder
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          ;
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Function.cs:**

```cs
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function(nameof(Function1))]
    public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "demo")] QueueMessage message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
    }
```

.csproj:

```json
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.13.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Console Response:**

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2023-12-21T13:30:44.145Z] Found C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\FunctionApp20\FunctionApp20\FunctionApp20.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2023-12-21T13:30:51.827Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 31452) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2023-12-21T13:30:51.980Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: queueTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-21T13:31:37.924Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2023-12-21T13:33:05.554Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'myqueue-items'.', Id=5ebXXXXXXX5ade3)
[2023-12-21T13:33:05.560Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: b47f66XXXXXXXXXXXXXd2793e21d, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2023-12-21T13:33:02.000+00:00
[2023-12-21T13:33:06.055Z] C# Queue trigger function processed: Hello world
[2023-12-21T13:33:06.155Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=5eb356d2-e5dc-XXXXXXXXXXXXd67025ade3, Duration=703ms)
```